# override `getResources()` of Context to work in xml

Tags: android, xml, resources, overriding

I have a custom `Resources` class where one can set Colors which will override the ones defined in res/values/colors. Every Activity Overrides the `getResources()` method to return my custom Resource-Object. If I recieve colors programatically (in java calling `getResources().getColor(R.color.xxx)` ) everything works as expected. The problem is inside a xml-layout file. If I define a color there (i.e using `textColor="@color/xxx"`), it will always use the one in /res/values/colors.xml and NOT my overriden ones. Is there a way to change this behavior, that while inflating from XML my custom-resource object is beeing used?

Comment: One way can be to put your custom color values inside the `color.xml'. Then you can access it from your Java file as well as xml file.

Comment: No one can ADD colors to colors.xml at RUNTIME!!!

Comment: Yes Sir. I agree. I think you misunderstood me. I was just suggesting that instead of overriding the default colors, why don't you add your custom colors in the xml file( NOT at runtime) by a different name and then use it instead. I am trying to just get your use case and need for the same.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri sry. I have designed my custom Resource-class to override MY own colors.xml. I'm working on a library and a client which uses it, wants to set custom-colors that better fits his own app.

Comment: okay. If its a library then it makes complete sense.  Interesting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I'm unable to find the actual implementation of `AttributeSet` I realized, that the whole idea was wrong. I guess that because the Resources are precompiled, they aren't sourced the same way using the `Resources` class. The solution is the Build-System itself. Beeing a library the Resources have a lower priority than the App which is using it. Therefore the app which is using my library can kind of override library Resources by defining own ones using the same name in its colors.xml.